# Using an enum within a nested class with Thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following class:

Types.java:

```
public class Types {
    public static class PC {
        public static enum Motherboard {
            OPTION1("option 1"),
            OPTION2("option 2"),
            OPTION3("option 3");

            private final String displayValue;

            private Motherboard(String displayValue) { this.displayValue = displayValue; }

            public String getDisplayValue() { return this.displayValue; }
        }
    };
};
```

In my Thymeleaf template I have:

```
<select name="select-motherboard">
    <option th:each="size : ${T(jre.maintainme.utils.strings.Types.PC.Motherboard).values()}" th:value="${size}" th:text="${size.displayValue}"></option>
</select>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. If however, I put the Motherboard enum into the Types Class, it does... Is there a way I'm missing to be able to nest enums in classes and use them in Thymeleaf?

Comment: Huh. That should work just fine. What happens if you run `System.out.println(OPTION1.getClass())`?

Comment: It comes out with ```class jre.maintainme.utils.strings.Types$PC$Motherboard```

EDIT:

Figured it out. I was using # originally to distinguish the classes, and also . but the correct was as that just pointed out is to use $ between the classes.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, instead of editing your question with the correct answer, post an answer to your own question (you can even accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

In order to go into nested classes, you need to add a $ between them. I.e:

```
${T(jre.maintainme.utils.strings.Types$PC$Motherboard)}
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I've got a Client class with an inner enum Type.
I tried accessing with ${T(my.package.path.Client$Type)} and it won't compile. :S

Answer (score 0):

What did work for me was the first thing you tried:

```
${T(com.my.package.path.Client.Type).values()
```

However, IntelliJ claims it can't resolve Type, but IntelliJ *lies*!